# how to run sql command in chef

Tags: sql-server, ruby, chef-infra

I want to run the below MSSQL command from a Chef cookbook on a windows server.

```
update RP2.rp2.USR02 SET UFLAG='0' WHERE BNAME='DDIC' AND MANDT='001'
```

If I run the chef-client from command prompt, its updating the DB. But I want this to work, when I run the Chef service instead of directly running the chef-client from command prompt, which is not working. I tried below code

```
path = File.join('D:', 'Program Files', 'Microsoft SQL Server', '110', 'Tools', 'Binn')


 execute 'run_sql_update_db' do
    cwd path
    command "SQLCMD.EXE -Q \"UPDATE RP2.rp2.USR02 SET UFLAG='0' WHERE BNAME='DDIC' AND MANDT='001';"
 end
```

This is not showing any error.

I have tried with .sql script as well. Below the code I tried

```
  execute 'run_sql_update_db' do
    cwd path
    command "SQLCMD.EXE -i D:\\TEMP\\update_db.sql"
  end
```

The update_db.sql have below content

`update RP2.rp2.USR02 SET UFLAG='0' WHERE BNAME='DDIC' AND MANDT='001'`

Please help.

Comment: Both of those are correct from the Chef side of things. If you turn up the log level to debug (`chef-client -l debug`) you can see the full output from the command. It might need authentication or something else.

Comment: @coderanger- Yes right. The chef-client user don't have access to the Data base, hence i didn't get expected results. I resolved this by using the DB user to run this command. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A token answer so this is marked as resolved.

User had to set Chef to log level debug (`chef-client -l debug`) and then could see that there was an error in the command.